# Python: how to display an item while iterating through a list (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am writing a speed-reader program where I take a .txt with a list of definitions and display the key-word while the definition is printed out word by word below, simulating a Spritz speedreader. This is all done in a Tkinter window.

I've made up a list keyword=i[0] that contains the keyword for every line (i) in the .txt, and a list definition=i[1:] that contains the definition, each word its own token.

For example, if line1 of the .txt is "bug: an error in a program" I need the output to look like this.

```
bug:

    an
```

then

```
bug:

    error
```

and so on until the end of the definition. Then, "bug" is replaced with the next word to be defined.

SO... how do I keep "bug" there, while running through each word of the definition? 
This is part of what I have. It also currently prints the words over one another, so I need to delete every word before it is replaced by another. This is my first time ever using Tkinter so bear with me.

```
def cycle_text(root, canvas, file_name, width, height, font_size, wpm):
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, width, height, fill='Beige')
    topics = write_title(file_name)
    information = write_info(file_name)
    pause = 60/wpm
    for i in topics:
        canvas.create_text(200, 200, text=i, font = ('Courier', font_size))
    for j in information:
        for z in j:
            canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=z, font = ('Courier', font_size))
            time.sleep(pause)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `create_` method, save the returned value to a variable. You can then switch it to different text with `config` or `itemconfig` rather than creating new ones over and over. For example, using `Label` widgets:

```
wordlist = ['an', 'error', 'in', 'a', 'program']

def nextword(self, which):
    definitionword.config(text=wordlist[which])
    if which+1 < len(wordlist):
        self.root.after(self.wpm*1000/60, lambda: nextword(which+1))

self.theword = Label(self.canvas, text='bug')
self.theword.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.definitionword = Label(self.canvas, text='')
self.definitionword.grid(row=1, column=0)

self.nextword(0)
```

This is an approximation. You'll need to use your own data structures and names.

If you'd rather use a `Canvas` widget's `create_text` instead of `Label`s, try something like:

```
self.definitionword = self.canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=wordlist[0])
self.canvas.itemconfig(self.definitionword, text=wordlist[1])
```

Basically, you'll keep the defined word separate from the list of words that comprise its definition, then repeatedly reconfigure the "words in the definition" widget to display text for the next word in the definition.

Don't use `time.sleep` to delay events in `tkinter` - the way `tkinter` updates its display makes `sleep` not function as you'd expect. Use the `after` method instead.

Check out the [tkinterbook on Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) for lots of great information about `tkinter`.